# A perfect blended circle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blending

I am trying to use the blend tool to make a gradient that wraps around like a circle, but I can only get it to go 3/4s of the way. Is there any way to get it to go the full 360 degrees?

Step 1 shows a circle being applied to the blend.
Step 2 shows the circle replacing the spine of the blend (object > blend > replace spine)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open one of the circle anchors where you want to start and end your gradient.
the example below shows the desire effect, all I did is the open the left anchor of the circle. I mean I converted the circle spine from a closed path to an open one.

[image]

ps. the white hole in the center appears because the diameter of the circle dose not have the same exact height of the two paths before blending them.

Comment: Obviously I'm missing something simple. What do you mean by opening and anchor point? Do you mean to remove the anchor on the left with the white arrow tool?

Comment: select the anchor that you want to break by the white arrow, then the properties bar will change to "anchor point" property bar. select `Cut path at selected anchor point`